flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin notifications icon not seen by Flutter in android studio
I have an Icon (called 'test.png') with white drawing 96x96 px in my drawables folder which I set using AndroidInitializationSettings('test'). However, when running the app and triggering a notification the icon is just a grey background, and I get following message in console:
PlatformException(invalid_icon, The resource test could not be found. Please make sure it has been added as a drawable resource to your Android head project., null, null)

What am I doing wrong?
The file exists, is in the correct folder, and is white with transparent background and 96px. Which other hoops do I have to jump through? :'(

try to change the name of image to app_icon and set it in folder drawable and folder drawable-21 and in the flutter local notification called the icon name without image extension

unfortunately this didn't work (no change), but thanks
